# Make IP.Board Forum Logo Change with Domain Redirect?

Tags: html, css, redirect

How can I make my forum logo recognize which domain name a person is using to get to my IP.Board and have it change to represent that URL?

For example (not my domain), I have a domain name called racecars.com and it is the main url for the IP.Board forum and the logo has racecars.com on the logo image.

But I also have a domain name called dragcars.com redirecting to the forum. I want the logo or forum software to recognize that URL redirect and call to a different forum logo representing that domain with dragcars.com and display it instead of the main logo.

Here is the code we've come up with, but we don't know where to put it (which file) and every place we've tried, it does not change the logo between the two URL's.

```
<!-- Logo Switch -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myTitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
var myTitle2 = myTitle.innerHTML; 
if (myTitle2 =="dragcars") {
$("img").attr({src:"logo_transparent2.png", alt:"logo2"});
}else { $("img").attr({src:"logo_transparent.png", alt:"logo1"});
}
</script>
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Some code from you would be nice. Do you have any html/css/js to show?

Comment: I just added some code we tried that did not work. As a side note, I didn't refresh the templates. So if you think the code is right, let me know and I'll add it back and refresh the forum templates.

Comment: And we don't know the correct location to insert that code.

Comment: So you redirect the users to the same domain? So from dragcars.com the user gets redirected to racecars.com? Does the title change?

Comment: The redirect is a 301 permanent, so the domain redirect displays permanently; it doesn't matter what you click on the forum. With that redirect setup from the registrar, it allowed me to setup title tag that shows up in the tab of the webpage, etc. This JavaScript is supposed to be able to recognize the URL via that title tag from the redirected URL I believe, and display the other forum logo representing the redirected url. Conversely, if the main url is used, it is supposed to display the other logo. Make sense?

Comment: Anyone else have any help they can offer on this?